# how to spring cloud gateway custom FilterFactory set response body

Tags: spring-cloud, spring-cloud-gateway

How to get spring cloud gateway custom FilterFactory setting body response,I created a custom filter extends AbstractGatewayFilterFactory . but I don't know how I am getting fail response
Please Help
here is my snippet

```
@Override
    public GatewayFilter apply(Object config) {
        return (exchange, chain) -> {
              chain?????  
}
```

Comment: problem solved 。

Comment: DataBuffer buffer = exchange.getResponse().bufferFactory().wrap(bytes);
                return exchange.getResponse().writeWith(Flux.just(buffer));